# How to display the jQuery Autocomplete response and select it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I hope you can help me with this. I am creating an Ajax autocomplete in my search form. I can get the response array. But I am having a hard time in displaying it in the UI. I can only get is the word 'undefined'. What I want is to perform an Ajax autocomplete then from that the user can select from the suggestions.

Here's my code so far.

```
$("#search-shop-input").autocomplete({

    source: function(request, response) {

         $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=seller/seller/getSellerNames',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: { keyword: request },
            success: function(data) {

                var d = '';

                $.each(data.shops, function(key,value) {

                   $.each(value, function(k,v) {
                        console.log(k + ":" + v); //want to get username only
                   });

                });

                //response(d);

            }
        });

    },

    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#seller_list").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },

    autoFocus: true,
    min_length: 0
});
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
shops: [{user_id: "162", username: "F_Francium_1"}, {user_id: "163", username: "F_Francium_2"},…]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through each JSON object in the shops array to begin with so this means you should then have access to the properties of each object using the 'this' keyword in the callback function. Try -

```
$.each(data.shops, function() {
    console.log(this.username);
}
```

or if you what to use the callback method with the index and object values.

```
$.each(data.shops, function (index, object) {
    console.log(object.username);
});
```